# Обособление деепричастного оборота (2)

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

Разрешите, пожалуйста, мои сомнения. Достаточно ли сильна в этом предложении связь между сказуемым и деепричастным оборотом, чтобы его не обособлять?

Быстро впитывается (,) не оставляя излишнего блеска.

Comment: Вот хорошая статья - описывает всё, что может вызвать сомнения, - "Когда деепричастные обороты не обособляются": https://www.tutoronline.ru/blog/kogda-deeprichastnyj-oborot-ne-obosobljaetsja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здравствуйте!

У нас полновесный, несомненный, со штампом "Уплочено!" деепричастный оборот, к тому ж распространённый ("излишнего"),

который прямо-таки вопиет: ОБОСОБЬ МЕНЯ!

*Впитывается, не оставляя чего бы то ни было,* - можно сказать, что и связи-то никакой со сказуемым нет, но - есть, слабенькая такое, но наличествует, и деепричастие продолжают рассматривать как добавочное к глаголу действие,

вопрос - доколе?

(Скоро, скоро уж мировое сообщество безоговорочно признает его, д., самостоятельной частью речи.)

ЗАПЯТАЯ НЕОБХОДИМА. Как воздух.

Answer (score 1):

Деепричастие или деепричастный оборот не обособляется, только если деепричастие переходит в разряд наречия (адвербализируется). Например: *Он сидя смотрел телевизор* — здесь *сидя* не обозначает добавочность действия, а указывает на его образ.

В вашем примере есть два действия: *впитывается* — основное, *не оставляя* — добавочное. Запятая нужна, так как это деепричастный оборот.